# Different inference result in AWS versus the Keras-Windows

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I trained my model in Keras with Tensorflow 2.5 (from tensorflow import keras) and I converted it to tensorflow model for inference using AWS SageMaker. The inference result is quite different. I reviewed the libraries and all of them are same version, feature extraction is the same one too. What else can I review?.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to [test inference on your local laptop using SageMaker local](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/blob/main/tensorflow_script_mode_local_training_and_serving) (runs the SageMaker TF inference container locally using docker). Then you could troubleshoot it very quickly (seconds to launch the container).
Additionally, you could debug the inference code using PyCharm ([this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/blob/main/tensorflow_script_mode_debug_local_training) debugs training, but it could be close enough).